# Why is Spyder throwing a syntax error when I try and import my own modules?

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder, anaconda3

I'm trying to figure out how to make my own modules and use them in Spyder, but for reasons I am ill equipped to figure out it is not as simple as everything online is telling me it should be. With all the approaches I've tried I seem to end up at the same syntax error (here the module is called module and it's in a folder called mymodules):

```
  File C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\IPython\\core\\interactiveshell.py:3460 in run_code
exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

Cell In\[15\], line 1
import mymodules.module

File C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\mymodules\\module.py:10
conda install pymed
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax\
```

I've tried several things that ultimately end with this error:

- putting my module in the current working directory
- putting the module in one of the sys.path directories
- addind a directory to sys.path and putting the module in there

Finally I tried the following (based on this article https://medium.com/@mcmanus_data_works/how-to-import-your-python-scripts-with-anaconda-on-mac-and-windows-9b3fe5544d9d):

- adding a folder to the site-packages folder of Anaconda, and putting an empty __init__.py file in that folder along with my module.

after doing this entering `import mymodules` no error was thrown but `import mymodules.module` or `from mymodules import module`  threw the syntax error and `import module` threw a 'ModuleNotFound' error.

At this point I decided I was stumped and maybe something is going on that's beyond me.
appreciate any help.

Comment: `conda install pymed` is not Python. Why is that in your module?

Comment: `conda install pymed` is a console command, and not valid Python code. Why is that in a file that should only contain Python code?

Comment: Well this inadvertently answers my question, I wasn't aware this error meant that that command was in my module text (didn't expect it to be in there because, as you say, its a console command). Removing it from the module solved the problem. Thank you both.